# How To Convert A Function Defined Using Mathematica's Block or Module Into Python

Tags: functions

Lets say I have the following function

```
circum[{{{x1_, y1_, z1_, w1_}, {x2_, y2_, z2_, w2_}, {x3_, y3_, z3_, 
 w3_}, {x4_, y4_, z4_, w4_}}}] := Block[{xx1 = 
Inverse[{{2 ({x4, y4, z4, w4} - {x1, y1, z1, w1}).({x4, y4, z4, 
         w4} - {x1, y1, z1, w1}), 
    2 ({x4, y4, z4, w4} - {x1, y1, z1, w1}).({x4, y4, z4, 
         w4} - {x2, y2, z2, w2}), 
    2 ({x4, y4, z4, w4} - {x1, y1, z1, w1}).({x4, y4, z4, 
         w4} - {x3, y3, z3, w3})}, {2 ({x4, y4, z4, w4} - {x2, y2,
          z2, w2}).({x4, y4, z4, w4} - {x1, y1, z1, w1}), 
    2 ({x4, y4, z4, w4} - {x2, y2, z2, w2}).({x4, y4, z4, 
         w4} - {x2, y2, z2, w2}), 
    2 ({x4, y4, z4, w4} - {x2, y2, z2, w2}).({x4, y4, z4, 
         w4} - {x3, y3, z3, w3})}, {2 ({x4, y4, z4, w4} - {x3, y3,
          z3, w3}).({x4, y4, z4, w4} - {x1, y1, z1, w1}), 
    2 ({x4, y4, z4, w4} - {x3, y3, z3, w3}).({x4, y4, z4, 
         w4} - {x2, y2, z2, w2}), 
    2 ({x4, y4, z4, w4} - {x3, y3, z3, w3}).({x4, y4, z4, 
         w4} - {x3, y3, z3, w3})}}].{({x4, y4, z4, w4} - {x1, y1, 
      z1, w1}).({x4, y4, z4, w4} - {x1, y1, z1, w1}), ({x4, y4, 
      z4, w4} - {x2, y2, z2, w2}).({x4, y4, z4, w4} - {x2, y2, z2,
       w2}), ({x4, y4, z4, w4} - {x3, y3, z3, w3}).({x4, y4, z4, 
      w4} - {x3, y3, z3, w3})}}, ((xx1)[[1]]*{x1, y1, z1, 
  w1} + (xx1)[[2]]*{x2, y2, z2, w2} + (xx1)[[3]]*{x3, y3, z3, 
  w3} + (1 - (xx1)[[1]] - (xx1)[[2]] - (xx1)[[3]])*{x4, y4, z4, 
  w4})]
```

How do I convert this Mathematica expression into Pyhton?. I really would like my code in Python to not have to evaluate this inverse and dot product six times when it only needs to do it once.

Comment: As stated, this is a question strictly about python, which is off topic here. A valid on-topic one would be e.g. "Is there an about way to convert this MMA function into its python equivalent?". Please edit the question to make it on-topic before it gets closed.

Comment: Where should I post it then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that you usually post questions about language conversions on the forum for the language you want to convert to. I suppose because a bunch of Python code on the Mathematica SE is unlikely to help anyone else here, but there's a higher chance of it helping someone on a Python forum. That being said, I'm very bored and if I include some Mathematica code perhaps it will be of some small use to a Mathematica user in the future.

As it is written, the code is a bit difficult to parse for me. Perhaps there's a reason why you need your matrix broken down into individually labelled variables. If you're okay simply defining a 4 x 4 matrix, then I think the following will work. In Mathematica code first:

```
circum[mat_] := Block[{
   xx1 = Inverse[
      2 Table[
          (mat[[4]] - mat[[i]]).(mat[[4]] - mat[[j]]),
          {i, 3},
          {j, 3}
        ]
      ].Table[
        Norm[mat[[4]] - mat[[i]]]^2,
        {i, 3}
      ]},
  {xx1[[1]], xx1[[2]], xx1[[3]], (1 - Total[xx1])}.mat
]
```

and in Python I would write:

```python
import numpy as np
def circum(mat):
  xx1 = np.dot(np.linalg.inv([[2*np.dot(mat[3] - mat[i], mat[3] - mat[j]) for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]), [np.linalg.norm(mat[3] - mat[i])**2 for i in range(3)])
  return(np.dot([xx1[0], xx1[1], xx1[2], 1 - np.sum(xx1)], mat))
```

Using `{{1, 1, 0, 16}, {4, 5, 15, 16}, {2, 12, 5, 16}, {7, 14, 16, 6}}` in Mathematica, and `np.array([[1, 1, 0, 16], [4, 5, 15, 16], [2, 12, 5, 16], [7, 14, 16, 6]]` in Python, I get `{5.29759, 4.2931, 6.59565, 5.36264}` as output from both programs (technically MMA gives exact answers because I didn't use `N`).

I think that defining them in terms of `Table` or `for` also makes it easier should you ever need to repurpose the code for matrices that are not 4 x 4. It should only take a few quick changes to some of the indices rather than type out n^2 terms. If for some reason you must absolutely use `{{x1, y1, z1, w1}, ...}` then it should actually be even easier to translate into Python, but much more tedious and I'm not quite that bored. The only things you would really need are `np.linalg.inv()` and `np.dot()`.